# Determining the x-y Values of Points with known Latitudes and Longitudes within Square Area

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have an issue to resolve and need expert assistance.
Given a 2km square kilometer (2km2) with midpoint at 1km and the Longitude and Latitude of the midpoint are known. Assuming that the Longitudes and Longitudes of the four boundary points [at (0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)] are determined, and the origins of the X and Y coordinates of the square start at zero (0, 0) to positive X and Y values with boundary at 2km respectively.

If there are about 100 places (or points) within this square with known Latitudes and Longitudes, how would I determine the respective x, y values (in km) of these 100 points with respect to the origins at zero?

Comment: It depend on the precision you want but I think for most practical purposes this can be modeled as 2D plane in which case you can just subtract longitude and latitude of the origin from longitude and latitude of a point to get $x$ and $y$

Comment: I love your suggestion. Thanks for the quick response. Actually I need close to 98% precision or even more. Please I would like if you will give me one sample of how to evaluate the value of x, y of a point from your suggestion.

Comment: Please how would I evaluate the values of x, y of a point after the subtraction of the latitude and longitude of the origin from that of a point of interest?